# BeautfilSoup return "None"

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to make a script to track prices on amazon. But I don't understand why it giving me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraping_amazon.py", line 12, in <module>
    price = soup.find('span', class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Here's my script so far :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/Sony-Vollformat-Digitalkamera-Megapixel-SEL-2870/dp/B00FWUDEEC/ref=sr_1_4?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=sony+a7&qid=1604245969&quartzVehicle=5-672&replacementKeywords=sony&sr=8-4'

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find('span', class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString').text

print(price)
```

I followed the same process than with my other webscraping script, they're working, but not him.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page contents are dynamically loaded using `javascript`. You have to use something like `selenium` in order to scrape pages that are dynamically loaded. Here is the full code to do it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/Sony-Vollformat-Digitalkamera-Megapixel-SEL-2870/dp/B00FWUDEEC/ref=sr_1_4?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=sony+a7&qid=1604245969&quartzVehicle=5-672&replacementKeywords=sony&sr=8-4'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(4)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')

price = soup.find('span', class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString').text

print(price)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
962,16 €
```

Comment: File "scraping_amazon.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Your chromedriver has to be in the same path as ur script. If it is not in the same path, then u have to specify the full file path in `webdriver.Chrome()`. Here is an example: `driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\Python\\chromedriver.exe')`

Comment: I don't know where is my chromedriver. I neved used that before ^^

Comment: Ok...If you don't have a chromedriver, download one from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads After downloading, place it in the same directory as ur script and run ur script

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLsession with some dummy user agent

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'
}
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://www.amazon.de/Sony-Vollformat-Digitalkamera-Megapixel-SEL-2870/dp/B00FWUDEEC/ref=sr_1_4?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=sony+a7&qid=1604245969&quartzVehicle=5-672&replacementKeywords=sony&sr=8-4',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find('span', class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString').text

print(price)
```

Comment: I tried with user agent before but it didn't work :/

Comment: @LaurieFalcon It works for me https://repl.it/repls/ParallelScratchyDisc